# PHP array replace key names only

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that I am retrieving from an alternative source, the keys are preset strings. I'm using $devices as an example of the array that I would retrieve.

I want to replace the key names of $devices with 1 to 1 match of $new_keys. Below code is what I have so far but I'm not getting the result I am looking for?

```
$devices = array('uniqueId' => '1234','status' => 'online','lastUpdate' => time(),'phone' => '1234','model' => 'test','contact' => 'admin'
$new_keys = array('IMEI','Status','Last Update','Phone','Model','Contact');            

for ($i = 0; $i < count($devices) - 1; $i++) {
    array_replace($devices[$i], $new_keys[$i]);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: With this code you will replace their content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at PHP function [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php). It does what you need:

```
$devices = array('uniqueId' => '1234','status' => 'online','lastUpdate' => time(),'phone' => '1234','model' => 'test','contact' => 'admin');
$new_keys = array('IMEI','Status','Last Update','Phone','Model','Contact');            

$fixed = array_combine($new_keys, array_values($devices));

// print_r($fixed);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [IMEI] => 1234
    [Status] => online
    [Last Update] => 1490179692
    [Phone] => 1234
    [Model] => test
    [Contact] => admin
)
```

Comment: Decent solution - better than the foreach loop I suggested. Forgot about `array_combine`.

Answer (score 1):

`array_replace` will replace the values where the keys match, not the keys themselves.

You're probably best creating a new array and merging the two in your loop. You need to swap aout `for` for `foreach`, and you also can't reference (I don't think) your `$devices` array with `$i`.

```
$devices = array('uniqueId' => '1234','status' => 'online','lastUpdate' => time(),'phone' => '1234','model' => 'test','contact' => 'admin'
$new_keys = array('IMEI','Status','Last Update','Phone','Model','Contact');            
$new_devices = array();

$i = 0;
foreach($devices as $key => $value) {
    $new_devices[$new_keys[$i]] = $value;
    $i++;
}
```

I'm not sure what you're actually doing here, but using this 1-to-1 relationship of old and new keys, based on their position, is asking for trouble!

Comment: Thanks, I tried your solution and also worked well. I went with axiac to keep it simple. In regards to the possible trouble. I'm still relatively new to programming php and was looking for a relatively simple solution to the problem. I figured there is a possibility of them being jumbled up, however as the returned data from the API is set and documented. I considered this low risk. However if there is any other reasons that could cause trouble. I am very much open to input! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$newArr = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($devices) - 1; $i++) {
$newArr[$new_keys[$i]]=$devices[$i];
}
$device = $newArr;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$arr = array_combine($new_keys,$devices);
print_r($arr);
```

Here is the [source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) which states Creates an array by using one array for keys and another for its values